# cmake: cross-compiling with additional libraries

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile an executable for raspberry on ubuntu.

I have configured crosstools-ng and I use cmake.
My executable use additional libraries (libfastcgi for example).
I have created a toolchain file for raspberry where CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH reference the binary generated by crosstolls-ng and a mounting point to the raspberry

The  cmake succeed, the find_library is ok, it succeed to find the additional libraries on the raspberry mounting point.

But the make command fails, the header files of the additional libraries are not found whereas they are located in the directory /usr/include on the raspberry, I have notice that the include path /mnt/raspberry/usr/include is not added to the compiler command line.

I have tried to add in the toolchain file the following command:
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    /media/raspberry/usr/include
    )

But then the cmake command fails to find pthread (it was ok before to add the include directory)

```
CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.0.2-Linux-i386/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/cmake-3.0.2-Linux-i386/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/opt/cmake-3.0.2-Linux-i386/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:178     (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
CMakeLists.txt:19 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```